# get active directory user information with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, active-directory

i have a react web app

i want to get active directory user information and check it if in a AD group

is that possible ?

What would be the way to make thid kind of api?

Comment: Have you tried searching NPM?, a quick search I found -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can use `Microsoft Graph API`. IMHO, you want to use AD as a Single Sign-On Authentication Server. If you haven't found a good post or tutorial how to do this yet, you can refer: [Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a React single-page app (SPA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react)